# Create a dropdown list in C#

Tags: c#, drop-down-menu

i am new to programming and I would like some help on how can I create a drop down list of Pass/ Fail in c#. Any help will be appreciated

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Match match;
        string pattern = @"\s*#\sfeatures+.+|\s*#\scalabash+.+";
        string replacement = " Step #... ";
        string result;


        // Read input file
        StreamReader inFile = new StreamReader(@"C:\Users\Desktop\file.txt");
        string input = inFile.ReadToEnd();
        inFile.Close();

        // matching pattern
        match = Regex.Match(input, pattern, RegexOptions.Multiline);
        while (match.Success)
        {
            // Console.WriteLine("'{0}'character found: {1} ", match.Value, match.Index);
            match = match.NextMatch();
        }

        // replace
        result = Regex.Replace(input, pattern, replacement);
        // Console.WriteLine(result);
        File.WriteAllText(@"C:\Users\Desktop\file.txt", result);
```

Comment: What?  This appears to be a console application.

Comment: Yes it is, and i spent hours on finding how i could implement a dropdown, but couldn't find any

Comment: What do you mean by "dropdown"?  Do you mean some sort of text-based display in the console window that looks and behaves like a GUI control?

Comment: Just give them a prompt. Did your prof really require you to put a combo box in a console application?

Comment: Yes just like a simple HTML dropdown list, where i can select either pass or fail

Comment: here is the confusion, console/terminal **normally** does not render html (unless you do something [crazy](http://askubuntu.com/questions/460022/using-terminal-as-a-web-browser)), so you cannot render drop downs in a console/terminal. Can you double check your question whether you require a webapp or a console application?

Comment: I think you've selected the wrong template type in your project. Definitely check the top of your assignment to make sure! Good luck with your homework :)

Comment: Yes i did got it wrong guys, i asked my professor and he said the same thing. Thanks for the help anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to create a Windows Forms Application.

In VS:

File > New > Prodject > Windows Forms Application

Drag and drop a ComboBox control onto the form:

Toolbox > All Windows Forms > ComboBox

Right click the Combo Box > Edit Items

Add your items to the list and done